# Getting thet derivative of a user defined function in terms of an auxiliary function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

I'm currently struggling with evaluation control when getting the derivative of a function (I dont know if that's the correct term here. Sorry, beginner). My function is of the form

```
f[vx_, vy_, omega_] :=
  c1 Sin[c2] FLat[x, vy, omega] + ... + cn Sin[n] FLat[vx, vy, omega]
```

where

```
FLat[x_] := Dp*Sin[Cp*ArcTan[Bp*x - Ep*(Bp*x - ArcTan[Bp*x])]];
```

and

```
x = ArcTan[(vy + af*omega)/vx + 0.5*bf*omega] - delta1;
```

When I evaluate `D[f, vx]`, I get a horrible expression in terms of `ArcTan` whereas I would prefer something in terms of `FLat'`. How can I control the evaluation of that function to obrtain a nice representation of my derivative?

Comment: I think the *easy* way is to evaluate the derivative before evaluating the definition of `FLat`; alternatively you can use `Block` to temporarily change the assignment made to `FLat` into something that doesn't evaluate to the def of your function eg `Block[{FLat=f},<your code here>]`;

Comment: Your code is incorrect: (1) `FLat` is called with three arguments in the definition of `f[]` and defined with only one. (2) `D[f, vx]` yields `0`. Just to be clear, did you mean `D[f[vx, vy, omega], vx]`? (3) What's `x = ArcTan...` got to do with it?  There is no variable `x` used in any of the executed code, only a pattern named `x` (i.e. `x_`).

Comment: Anyway, my answer was going to be to inactivate `FLat`, but whether and how that would work depends on the actual code it would be applied to.

Answer (score 1):

I will use a simplified version of your function `f` in this discussion because you don't give us the full form. Hopefully, the simplified version will be adequate,

```
f[vx_, vy_, omega_] := c1 Sin[c2] flat[vx, v y, omega] + c3 Sin[c4] flat[vx, vy, omega]
```

If the derivitive is taken before `flat` is defined, there is no difficulty.

```
D[f[vx, vy, omega], vx]
```

> ```
> c1 Sin[c2] Derivative[1, 0, 0][flat][vx, vy, omega] + 
>   c3 Sin[c4] Derivative[1, 0, 0][flat][vx, vy, omega]
> ```

But after `flat` is defined by code such as

```
With[{x = ArcTan[(vy + af omega)/vx + 0.5 bf omega] - delta1}, 
  flat[vx_, vy_, omega_] =
    Dp Sin[Cp ArcTan[Bp x - Ep (Bp x - ArcTan[Bp x])]]];
```

Mathematic will use that definition and

```
Short[D[f[vx, vy, omega], vx], 4]
```

gives the complicated result

[image: result]

However, it is possible to generate a cell showing the same result as obtained before `flat` was defined in the following way:

```
Block[{flat, $Post = Inactivate[#, flat] &},
  Print[D[f[vx, vy, omega], vx]]]
```

> ```
> c1 Sin[c2] Derivative[1, 0, 0][flat][vx, vy, omega] + 
>   c3 Sin[c4] Derivative[1, 0, 0][flat][vx, vy, omega]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use the FullSimplify function, and also u can storage your derivative in another function.

```
FlatDeriv=FullSimplify[f,vx];
```

> Then you can use the replace comand in terms of visualization. Of course it will only work if the derivative has Flat[] on it. let me aclare it with an example.

```
f = Exp[2*x];

deriv = D[f, {x, 2}]

4 E^(2 x)
```

> Then Use the replace comand to replace the fuction in terms of the original function

```
deriv /. Exp[2x] -> "f"
```

> The result will be

```
4 f
```